# Django-celery tables spontaneously dropped

Tags: mysql, django, celery, django-celery

I deployed and started up a Django celery-based project on Friday night. On Sunday at 6:10pm, apparently all the djcelery tables disappeared from my database, causing an immediate shutdown of Celery. (I had this in a log file, but a coworker deleted it.) I don't think anyone was in the system on Sunday.

I can't think of much to explain it, other than the fact that according to the log, tasks were taking about 5 minutes to run, and were being triggered every 1 minute. (I don't know enough about Celery to know if this would cause a problem.)

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? Should I lodge a bug report? Are there any situations in which Django or Celery would drop tables? All other tables were left untouched. Running a south migration restored the missing tables, but who knows if the problem will recur.

The application uses a MySQL database which it shares (along with settings.py and a few other things) with a Django application run through Apache. It's running on a RHEL VM. The application is launched like this:

```
sudo -u apache bash -c "nohup `pwd`/bin/django celeryd --beat --purge --loglevel=INFO >> $LOG &"
```

Incidentally, the application is currently running, yet all those tables are empty - not sure what to read from that.

Comment: Celery definitely doesn't drop tables, and there have been no such reports before.  The --purge argument you have there will delete all tasks currently waiting for execution though.

Comment: Interesting. I'm completely baffled why this would happen on an unattended VM after several days of running correctly.